# window.onload not working while body onload works

Tags: javascript, html

this is my first question here but I hope that I am on point and give all nessecary info. I need to use window.onload to make a page scripted in the head of my html code with type="text/view" to show.

When I put this code in the body and use

```
<body onload="loadWelcomePage()">

    function loadWelcomePage() {
        var welcomePageContent = document.getElementById('welcomeview');
        var profilePageContent = document.getElementById('profileview');
        var showPage = document.getElementById('contentSpace');

        showPage.innerHTML = welcomePageContent.innerHTML;

    }
```

However when I copy the same code to a js file the same function won't load. What am I doing wrong. Ill post the replacement code in the js file that I use below.

```
window.onload = function() {displayView};

function displayView() {
   var welcomePageContent = document.getElementById('welcomeview');
   var profilePageContent = document.getElementById('profileview');
   var showPage = document.getElementById('contentSpace');

   showPage.innerHTML = welcomePageContent.innerHTML;
}
```

I need to use javascript and not jQuery to complete the task.

Comment: how about using `document.onload = function(){}` instead?

Comment: `window.onload = displayView` no parenthesis. Never seen `type="text/view" ` before...Niether has Google...

Comment: the type="text/view" is used in order to keep the browser from rendering the code until I assign it to a div using the above code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> function() {displayView};
> ```

Just mentioning a variable doesn't do anything.

If you want to call a function, then you have to call it (e.g. with `()`).

```
function() {displayView(); };
```

---

You could also just bypass the creation of a function which does nothing except call another function:

```
window.onload = displayView;
```

(Note that the browser will call the function when the event fires, you aren't calling it yourself in this case, so the `()` should be omitted, otherwise you call it *immediately* and assign the *return value* to `onload`.)

Comment: I've tried to write that and also displayView() but still the page ends up empty compared to the body onload function :/

Comment: @LuckAss Any chance you could include an MVCE inside your question, cause Quentin's suggestion is exactly what you need (unless there are some hidden factors, where you might get an error in your console which leads to your site being empty, but this is hard to check without having an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked now and I also removed the redundant function as you mentioned. Reason it didn't work first time was that I had a missing " in my .js import. So your answer was correct. :)